# RoR3 and MySQL error: dyld: Symbol not found: _mysql_init

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am troubleshooting a problem with MySQL for my Ruby on Rails 3.0.5 application, Mac OS X 10.6.

I installed MySQL version 5.1 and I am getting this error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _mysql_init
  Referenced from: /Users/manny/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _mysql_init
  Referenced from: /Users/manny/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

Trace/BPT trap
```

I tried to install MySQL v5.5, but the error still occurs. I installed MySQL from a .dmg.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the `mysql2` gem?

Comment: thanks tadman, it looks I am move next, this error is out. Now if I am trying rake --trace db:migrate, it should create database, but I am getting following error - do you have, please, an idea, in which could be problem again - http://pastebin.com/3eV9v21Z? Thanks

Comment: That really should be a separate question, but that's not a valid `.rake` file. That's a shell command that should be run on its own. If you want to define rake tasks, generally it starts with something like `namespace`.

Comment: Can you please post the command that is generating this error?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to remove MySQL and reinstall it, I did just with the following commands.  It's very simple to do from your terminal and will solve your issues:

```
rvmsudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config --with-opt-lib=/usr/local/mysql/lib
```

I hope this might help you to solve the issues.

Comment: This is the correct answer, and it works whether you're using the mysql2 gem or mysql.  It has to do with a mismatch with 64bit and 32bit libraries.  I also made sure the mysql server, client, and connector dmgs were the 64bit ones, then reinstalled the gem.

Answer (score 0):

Give the following a go...

```
# Use mysqldump to backup your databases to text files!
# Stop the database server
sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
edit /etc/hostconfig and remove the line MYSQLCOM=-YES-
rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
```

Then...

```
# Install Homebrew if you have not got it.
brew install mysql
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql dir=/usr/local \ --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/bin/mysql_config
```

That's assuming your homebrew prefix is /usr/local

Otherwise you could always [download](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) the required MySQL Version, install and run the following...

```
env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

Be sure to have your paths set in you bash and dont go about mysql2 0.2.7 with Rails.

Comment: I wouldn't delete the version of MySQL that OS X provides, if I were you. There's really no harm in keeping it there (except for the extra disk space).

Answer (score 0):

I tried numerous solutions found on the net. Finally I decided to do it another way. Reason for this is that most solution come with fixes for binding problems, that can be related back to troubles during the installation. Just a matter of authorization.

First removed the DBI and DBD / DBD::mysql files and folders from the Perl libraries 
folder in:

```
/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level
```

After that I started clan via a sudo

```
sudo cpan
```

In there I installed first DBI and after that DBD::mysql

```
install DBI
install DBD::mysql
```

And everything finally worked! Hope this helps, someone. A simple solution. It did cost me 2 days to debug and figure out.